# Laravel 5.7 SendEmail is not working properly

Tags: laravel

I am sending email using laravel 5.7 but i found following error " (1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Mail\UserRequest' not found" Need help

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
//use \App\Mail\SendMail;
use App\Mail\UserRequest;
class ContactusController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('contactus');
    }

     public function sendmail(Request $req)
    {

        $msgdata = array('subject'=>$req->subject,'email'=>$req->email, 
        'name'=>$req->name,'body'=>$req->message);
         Mail::to('dddddddd@dddsdsf.com')->send(new UserRequest($msgdata));
        return view('contactus');
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the same with a valid email?

Comment: Where are you using UserRequest?

Comment: By default laravel uses smtp to send emails. It means you have to configure email access first in `config/mail.php`.

Comment: @Martin how can i do this?

Comment: @Suniltc I am sending email wth UserRequest but still gives same error for UserRequest

Comment: Fill config file with your access data. You have to fill at least `host`, `port`, `from` and your credentials `username` and `password`. Configuration depends of your e-mail account provider's.

Comment: Please can you show the code where you're using `UserRequest`.

Comment: search `UserRequest` from you code editor and check where you are using that and remove or replace that based upon your need

Comment: @KamleshPaul sorry code is edited i am sending old code

Comment: @smitaranipatil please add `UserRequest.php` code as well it seem something wrong with namespace or you can try once `composer dump-autoload`